# Possibilities for the first four positions at the World Cup $2014$

Tags: combinatorics

> $32$ nations participated in the World Cup $2014$.
>
> How many possibilities were there for the order of the first four positions?

In general,

$$32 \choose 4$$

gives us the possibilities to choose $4$ nations out of $32$ nations. This doesn't include the possible positions of the $4$ nations though. For $4$ nations, there are $4!$ possibilities to rank them, so overall, we have

$${32 \choose 4} 4!$$

possibilites for the order of the first four positions.

What confuses me is that I get the same value by applying the formula

$${n! \over (n - k)!}$$

for $k \le n$.

But in our lecture notes, an example for this formula was the question: "How many possibilities are there to distribute $k$ students on $n$ places?". But in this case, wouldn't $k$ and $n$ be switched like "How many possibilites are there to distribute $32$ nations on $4$ positions?", which means that we would have $k > n$. What am I missing here?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're misunderstanding anything. You can call the larger of the two numbers $k$, $n$, $m$, $x$, $y$, smiley face... it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your reasoning is correct for the number of possibilities for the first four positions.

The distinction you make between switching $k$ and $n$ seems arbitrary. We could equivalently see the problem as distributing 4 positions among 32 nations.

Comment: That makes indeed sense, thanks!